# Module CSS And JS not available in static files

Tags: magento2, layout, javascript, css

Having trouble getting past 404 errors with css and js.

```
/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/routeid_index_index.xml


<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Vendor_Module::css/custom.css" />
        <script src="Vendor_Module::js/custom.js"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Display" name="Display" template="Vendor_Module::index.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Files are located here

```
/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/web/css/custom.css
/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/web/js/custom.js
```

static deploy doesn't seem to do the trick nor does manually clearing the cache

Comment: /Vendor/Module/etc is always for configuration and di files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to keep file inside **view** folder instead of **etc** folder.
New path will be,

```
/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/css/custom.css
/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/custom.js
```

**Run upgrade and deploy command.**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
rm -rf pub/static/frontend/* pub/static/adminhtml/* var/cache/ var/generation/ var/page_cache/ var/view_preprocessed/ var/composer_home
php -dmemory_limit=6G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
chmod -Rf 777 pub/ var/
```

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I was coding in the middle of the night and just couldn't see it